# Getting search results from respective crawlers of multisite with single Coveo index

Tags: coveo

I am using Sitecore 8.2 with Coveo 4.0.

I'm working on a multisite solution with two sites and created two crawlers inside a single index.

How can I make sure that on the search page data comes from the correct crawler of every site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter the results based on Site name. The below example

```
Coveo.$('#search').on("buildingQuery", 
    function(e, args) {
        args.queryBuilder.constantExpression.add("<%= ToCoveoFieldName("site") %> = '<%=Sitecore.Context.Site.Name%>'");
    })
    .coveoForSitecore('init', CoveoForSitecore.componentsOptions);
```

you can visit the below Coveo forums on this query.

https://answers.coveo.com/questions/4937/setting-up-indexes-for-multi-site-sitecore-solutio.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. It a valuable thing for me.

Answer (score 3):

The alternative is to use Coveo filter expression rules if you have a pro license of Coveo.
Coveo provides filter expression based on rule engine, where you can define the rule of child item of your website root or can compare the specific field value such as site field. you need to add expression rule on your Coveo search interface item - 
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot brother, as always you rock.